# React library for Sorting, Searching, Filtering and Pagination

Tags: reactjs, sorting, search, filter, pagination

I am working on a requirement in React where I need to have Sorting, Searching , Filtering and Pagination features to grid table data ( API response ). I want to know the best library I can use to get these features in React. I have been researching and I found many libraries like ag-grid, react-table, bootstrap etc. and its really confusing which one to opt.
Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

I have using react-table and recommend it.

Comment: Can you please point me to any of the examples or videos that can help me.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/examples/package/react-table
https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-awesome-tables-with-react-table-963955fd9262